# PHP's pg_connect() appears to be slower on a new

Tags: php, postgresql, silverstripe, apachebench

Got an obscure one. Been at this one for weeks. Here is what we’re doing:

- Upgrade of Silverstripe 3.1 -> 3.7
- Upgrade of Platform. PHP 5.6 -> 7.4, Postgres 9.5 -> 13
- Old system is running mod_php, New is running PHP_FPM
- Parallel hosting systems running. Old and New. Both have identical resources.
- Performance tests run on both systems for Old -> New comparisons.
- Both platforms consist of two App nodes, and one DB node

Most tests are great. PHP 7.4 obviously smokes the old system. But one test is Apache Bench just hitting home page. Which shows a pretty serious degradation on the New system. Digging further into this, we created a series of test files for Apache Bench to hit that isolate specific things - Static HTML, Raw PHP, PHP + Raw pg_ commands and queries.

All thrash the old system except the latter. DB interactions. So drilling down further we created a new target file that simply does a pg_connect() and immediately closes it, then hit that with Apache Bench. Same result as the query test script. Suggesting the deficit is in the action of pg_connect(). Database connections.

Clearly there's a lot of variables in this issue. And I'm loath to pack this question out with a bunch of details about the tests (and other tests like pgbench) until needed. I'm more hoping to stumble across someone who has observed a similar issue with pg_connect() specifically, and has even the most random idea for an angle to test.

Other testing ideas would be welcome. One thing we are trying to work out right now is how to get connection timing from pgbench to see if the issue exists on Postgres itself. Our tests are as follows:

- Apache Bench hitting several target pages
- PGBench (showing the new system performing better than the old)
- [PHP test](http://www.php-benchmark-script.com/)
- jMeter is being set up now

**UPDATE**

We've done a bit of manual digging in the Postgres logs in each environment, and see something a bit strange looking at the received/authorised log entry pairs like this:

```
2021-05-19 11:34:25.708 NZST,,,404734,"10.220.218.21:50560",60a44f01.62cfe,1,"",2021-05-19 11:34:25 NZST,,0,LOG,00000,"connection received: host=xx.xx.xx.xx port=50560",,,,,,,,,""
2021-05-19 11:34:25.908 NZST,"db_user","db_name",404734,"xx.xx.xx.xx:50560",60a44f01.62cfe,2,"authentication",2021-05-19 11:34:25 NZST,7/486524,0,LOG,00000,"connection authorized: user=db_user database=db_name",,,,,,,,,""
```

I captured a bunch of these pairs on both environments (Old and New) and calculated the gap between the recieved log message and the authentication log message.

On Old, the average is 0.011s. On New, the average is 0.195s. Difference aside, this makes no sense, as the test page on the application node of that environment takes ~0.02s to complete in full.

Comment: Are you connecting to Postgres via TCP or unix socket?

Comment: @Siguza TCP on both environments

Comment: Could you try connecting via unix socket and see if that makes a difference? If nothing else, just to rule it out...

Comment: How did you use pgbench?  To match your described use case, you would need to use the -C option.

Comment: What is the PostgreSQL authentication method?

Comment: In your log files, do the `xx` obscure an IP address, or a hostname?

Comment: Hi @jjanes, it's an IP address. Also the app node connection strings for pg_connect use the DB node's IP address too. So no DNS issue. It's odd, pgbench run locally on the DB node shows New outperforms the Old. Simple example of the pgbench commands we're using is `pgbench -c 12 -j 6 -t 10 -C pgbench`. It's like Postgres itself is running faster on New, until an external connection comes in.